# Perform operation on entire buffer, without changing the cursor position

Tags: vim

Consider a scenario, when you are editing a C file in `vim`. & you have used a mix of <kbd>spaces</kbd> & <kbd>tabs</kbd>s. & you need to convert all of them to <kbd>spaces</kbd>.

There is a utility, called `expand`, which performs this task intelligently & it's a preferred way than `s/\t/<4 spaces>/g`. We can use this command in vim using `:%!expand -t4`. Typically, I map a function key, say <kbd>F11</kbd> for this.

Similarly, we can use any other command in vim.

The problem is when you run any such operation on entire buffer, the cursor position changes & can be irritating at times.

Hence, the question is, **how to perform an operation on entire buffer, without changing cursor position?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor position can be restored by using the *latest jump mark*:

```
``
```

If you also want to maintain the exact window view, use `winsaveview()` / `winrestview()`.

The [anwolib - Yet another vim library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) has a handy `:KeepView` command for that:

```
:KeepView %!expand -t4
```

Comment: Yikes, I seem to have re-invented the wheel. `winsaveview()` / `winrestview()` is a great solution...

Answer (score 1):

For such a case, we can use marks (e.g. `mA`). The mapping would be:

```
:nmap <F11> mZ:%!expand -t4<CR>`Z
```

However, there is still a catch. The screen scroll position may change, when operating on entire buffer.
This can be handled by using 2 marks as below:

```
:nmap <F11> mZHmY:%!expand -t4<CR>'Yzt`Z
```

Explanation:

1. Mark current position. (<kbd>mZ</kbd>)
2. Go to top of screen. (<kbd>H</kbd>)
3. Mark this line. (<kbd>mY</kbd>)
4. Run your filter. (<kbd>:%!expand -t4</kbd>)
5. Go to line Y. (<kbd>'Y</kbd>)
6. Make it top of screen. (<kbd>zt</kbd>)
7. Go to your mark. (<kbd>`Z</kbd>)

Now, when you press the mapped key, <kbd>F11</kbd>, the filter runs on the buffer & the cursor remains at its proper location.

Answer (score 0):

you can just:

```
:your expand cmd|norm! ``
```

you can map it to `<F11>` if you like. but better use `nnoremap`

I just saw you mentioned in your question:

> Similarly, we can use any other command in vim

If you want to do that, the reliable solution would be wrap the "any other command" in a function, and before/after the main logic, save/restore the cursor position. Because "**any other command**" could change the (back tick) mark, even the marks you defined.

Comment: Did not understand `norm! \`\`` .. How exactly is it supposed to be used?